# Why can't I get Rested or Well Rested?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I sleep in rented beds and my bed in Jorrvaskr (with the Companions) and no matter how long I sleep I don't get the notification that I'm rested or well rested anymore.

I've looked at my active effects to check for Lycanthropy or Vampirism and all I have are positive effects.

I have slept in rented beds immediately after receiving blessings and having all diseases cured at the shrine of Mara.

What are other reasons I might not be able to get rested or well rested?

Comment: What I normally do in situations like this would be go to the Magic menu and go down to Active Powers (or something like that, I think it's the last option) and check the active magic.  Usually helps.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You've got the Lover's Stone active.

It [doesn't stack](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Standing_Stone#Notes) with the Rested / Well Rested / Lover's Comfort effects.

Comment: Confirmed! I tested by activating the Mage Stone and then going to sleep.  I woke up rested again.  
"You've got the Lover's Stone active." So matter of fact and in fact accurate. :-)  You are good.

Comment: ah, I never noticed this. Great! Another reason to take a utility stone rather than an XP stone once you have access to a house n spouse. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

One of the effects of being a Werewolf is

> Beast Blood
>   Becoming a Werewolf bestows the Beast Blood ability, which grants a 100% resistance to all diseases in both human and beast forms, but disallows you to acquire resting bonuses.

as noted [here.](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Werewolves)

Beast Blood is listed as a positive effect under Active Effects for its 100% Resistance to Disease but the lack of restful sleep is an unlisted side effect.

One of the possible bugs found after being cured is not receiving the well rested status as described [in this post.](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615805-/61123080)

Fixes to the bug are described in [that post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615805-/61123080) and under the [Cure section found here](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lycanthropy#Curing_Lycanthropy)

Another possibility might be that you have the Lover Stone Active Effect. You cannot get the Well Rested Effect if you already have the bonus from the Stone as noted both in [this section describing sleep](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sleeping) and in [this section under "Notes"](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Standing_Stone#Notes) for the Stone's effect.

Comment: I have never had or been cured of Beast Blood.  Other thoughts?  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the Lover's Stone "blessing"?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem (never being able to get any type of "rested" bonus) and discovered that was a stuck quest called
*PlayerSleepQuest*.

Since nearly every scripted activity in Skyrim is a "quest" of some sort (at least internally), it's possible that a previous execution of the script did not complete properly; I've found this can happen from a crash or even using "qqq" from the command shell to fast-quit. Additionally, you can only have one *instance* of any given quest active at a time.

Luckily the solution is pretty simple:

1. From your current game, use the **~** key to enter the command
   console.
2. Type **help PlayerSleepQuest** to get the questID.  It should be **000FC1A2**, but if your's is different for some odd reason, then be sure to use whatever ID is shown for the remaining steps.
3. Type **stopquest 000FC1A2** (press Enter)
4. Type **resetquest 000FC1A2** (press Enter)

The next time you sleep, the **PlayerSleepQuest** should activate properly and provide the appropriate feedback on screen and be shown in your active powers list.

(*Disclaimer: I have absolutely no idea how doing this might interact with any currently active Lycanthropy or Vampirism character state!  Be sure to have a good/known save to revert to should things go haywire!*)

Comment: How would it happen from improperly exiting the game (qqq/crash) unless it was writing a save at the time and you load that save?

Answer (score -1):

Turns out if you EVER use the Lovers Stone, it messes up the Rest capability.  Even though I had long ago changed back to Mage and Warrior stones, I still couldn't rest.

Comment: This adds nothing new to the existing answers.

Answer (score -2):

It's either Lycanthropy or Lover's Stone, they're the only two ways.